# Jenkins Pipeline as Code with Docker Error

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For one of my projects that I have on GitHub, I wanted to build it as a docker image and push it to my docker hub. The project is a sbt one with a Scala codebase.

Here is how my JenkinsFile is defined:

```
#!groovy

node {
  // set this in Jenkins server under Manage Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global Credentials
  docker.withRegistry('https://hub.docker.com/', 'joesan-docker-hub-credentials') {
    git credentialsId: '630bd271-01e7-48c3-bc5f-5df059c1abb8', url: 'https://github.com/joesan/monix-samples.git'

    sh "git rev-parse HEAD > .git/commit-id"
    def commit_id = readFile('.git/commit-id').trim()
    println comit_id

    stage "build" {
      def app = docker.build "Monix-Sample"
    }

    stage "publish" {
      app.push 'master'
      app.push "${commit_id}"
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried to run this from my Jenkins server, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFile$3.invoke(GitSCMFile.java:167)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFile$3.invoke(GitSCMFile.java:159)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$3.invoke(GitSCMFileSystem.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.AbstractGitAPIImpl.withRepository(AbstractGitAPIImpl.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.withRepository(CliGitAPIImpl.java:65)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem.invoke(GitSCMFileSystem.java:157)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFile.content(GitSCMFile.java:159)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFile.contentAsString(SCMFile.java:338)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:232)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Since this is running inside a VM on Azure, I thought the VM was not able to reach outside, but that seems not to be the case as I was able to ssh into the VM and git pull from the Git repo. So what is the problem here? How could I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the exact same error. My setting:

- Pipeline build inside a dockerized Jenkins (version 2.32.3)
- In the configuration of the job, I specified a check out into a subdirectory: Open the configuration, e.g. `https://myJenkins/job/my-job/configure`. At the bottom, see section `Pipeline` -> `Additional Behaviours` -> `Check out into a sub-directory` with `Local subdirectory for repo` set to, e.g., `my-sub-dir`.
- Expectation: Upon check out, the `Jenkinsfile` ends up in `my-sub-dir/Jenkinsfile`.
- Via the option `Script path`, you configure the location of the `Jenkinsfile` so that Jenkins can start the build. I put `my-sub-dir/Jenkinsfile` as value.

I then received the exception you pasted in your question. I fixed it by setting `Script Path` to `Jenkinsfile`. If you don't specify a sub-directory for check out, then still try double checking values for `Script Path`.

Note: I have another Jenkins instance at work. There I have to specify `Script Path` including the custom check out sub-directory (as mentioned in Expectation above).

Comment: I'm glad that someone else had the same problem and managed to fix it, Could you please elaborate on how you fixed it? I could not understand from what you have described above on how you solved the problem. Therefore could you be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: Tried to clarify, please comment.

Comment: Where do I find the Additioal Behaviors in Jenkins?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you using? Though your response says that you experienced the same problem, I was not able to resolve my problem based on what you describe! I would request you to elaborate it a bit more!

Answer (score 5):

for me unchecking "lightweight checkout" fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

GO TO Job-->Config-->Pipline and uncheck checkbox lightweight checkout"

[image]

> lightweight checkout : selected, try to obtain the Pipeline script contents >directly from
>   the SCM without performing a full checkout. The advantage of this mode
>   is its efficiency; however, you will not get any changelogs or polling
>   based on the SCM. (If you use checkout scm during the build, this will
>   populate the changelog and initialize polling.) Also build parameters
>   will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode. Only
>   selected SCM plugins support this mode.